# iTunes XML attributes

Tags: xml, itunes

I'm trying to better understand the various attributes in the iTunes plist XML file. For the life of me, I can't find this documented at all on Apple's developer site. The best I can come up with is:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/iTunesLibraryFrameworkReference/

Some of the class references overlap with what you'll see in the iTunes XML. However, I'm unable to find reference to things like "File Folder Count" and "Library Folder Count" for track entities in the XML file.

Can anyone point to proper iTunes XML documentation? If that's not available, does anyone know what "File Folder Count" and "Library Folder Count" refers to?

In my own XML, "File Folder Count" is predominantly 4 or 5. I'm not sure why.

```
beatmixed:iTunes mhite$ more iTunes\ Library.xml | grep "File Folder Count" | sort | uniq -c
   1            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>2</integer>
   1            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>3</integer>
27695           <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
1369            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
```

Similarly, "Library Folder Count" is predominantly 1 or 2:

```
beatmixed:iTunes mhite$ more iTunes\ Library.xml | grep "Library Folder Count" | sort | uniq -c
1470            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
27595           <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>2</integer>
   1            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>3</integer>
```

Any pointers or help appreciated in how to interpret these two items and their meaning.

Comment: I'm merging three separate iTunes libraries comprising ~10k tracks, and my File Folder Counts break down like so: `4`: 79%, `undefined`: 14%, `5`: 7%, `3`: 0.1%

Answer (score 1):

This is more a few datapoints than a real answer, but:

After way too many hours fighting CPU-consuming Music.app (FKA iTunes) libraries, I wrote a few AppleScripts to do things like deleting the artwork in every track.
When exporting the resulting no-artworks library as an XML, *all* the `File Folder Count` and `Library Folder Count` are `-1`. And a new library created from scratch and importing said XML contains no artwork.

This is curious because the XML file for a library with artworks will contain a field named `Artwork Count` for tracks with artworks, but that field seems to be ignored. Even if you delete it, when the app imports the XML, it will reimport/regenerate the artworks.

However, that same XML lists most tracks with `File Folder Count` with a value of `5` and `Library Folder Count` of `1`. So my guess is that this is somehow a flag for the app to recreate the artworks (and maybe other stuff).

Those `5` and `1` values seem to be independent of the number of artworks contained by the track; I have seen them in tracks with 0, 1, 2 and 19 artworks.

For 3 tracks whose file is missing in disk, both values are `-1`.

To clarify my context: my library with artworks is prone to cause Music.app, AMPLibraryAgent and AMPArtworkAgent to use over 100% CPU for minutes when they should be idling. My library with artworks removed is (for now?) free of this problem.